# C: removing minimum element of a Binary Heap

Tags: c

I'm working on a C implementation of a binary heap where the smallest element is at the base of the tree instead of the largest. And then, each next element in the tree is larger than the previous one.

My problem is when I remove the smallest element of the heap. Here is my code for defining a binary heap, initializing one, and removing the minimum element.

```
struct BinaryHeap
{
    int capacity;
    int size;
    int *heap;
};

void init_heap(struct BinaryHeap *heap_ptr, int capacity)
{
    heap_ptr->capacity = capacity;
    heap_ptr->size = 0;
    double n = ceil(pow(2, log10(capacity)/log10(2)));
    heap_ptr->heap = (int *)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
}

int remove_heap(struct BinaryHeap *heap_ptr)
{
    if (heap_ptr->size > 0)
    {
        int min_item = heap_ptr->heap[1];
        heap_ptr->heap[1] = heap_ptr->heap[heap_ptr->size];

        heap_ptr->size--;
        heap_ptr->heap[1] = NULL;  // I get a warning here

        if (heap_ptr->size > 0)
        {
            heapify(heap_ptr, 1);  // helper function which percolates the heap after removal
        }
        return min_item;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`NULL` is for null pointers, not for integer values. You need to set it to some other unattainable value. For example, if you can only have zero or positive numbers in the heap, you could set it to a negative value.

If your values can span the whole range of integers, then you need some other way of keeping track of unused entries. for example by having a second array containing a boolean flag saying if the corresponding value in `heap` is valid or not.